# XValueText font color in Pie Chart not changing

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am creating Pie Chart using MPAndroidCharts Library. Everything went well, just one problem i m facing regarding ValueTextColor

[Pie_chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmhGW.png)

[Pie_chart(zoomed in)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlOAU.png)

XValuesLabel are coming in White font Color, and YValueLabel in Black fontColor.
I want both of it in black color, but somehow setValueTextColor() is not making any impact in XValuesLabel

```
Log.d("PIECHART dataset", "addDataSet started");
ArrayList yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList xEntrys = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
    if(yData[i]>0) {

    switch(i){
        case 0:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "banana"));
            break;
        case 1:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "guava"));
            break;
        case 2:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "apple"));
            break;
        case 3:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "pineapple"));
            break;
        case 4:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "mango"));
            break;
        case 5:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "papaya"));
            break;
        case 6:
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], "dates"));
            break;
        default : ;
    }

    }
}
//create the data set

pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "");
pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(15f);
pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.RED);/* this line not working */
pieDataSet.setSelectionShift(10f);
pieDataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(80.f);
pieDataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(1f);
pieDataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(0.9f);
pieDataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
//pieDataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);

//add colors to dataset
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add(Color.rgb(156,254,230));
colors.add(Color.rgb(159,185,235));
colors.add(Color.rgb(143,231,161));
colors.add(Color.rgb(160,239,136));
colors.add(Color.rgb(200,246,139));
colors.add(Color.rgb(176,219,233));
colors.add(Color.rgb(183,176,253));

pieDataSet.setColors(colors);

///// disabling chart legend
pieChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

Log.d("PIECHART dataset2", xEntrys.size()+" ");

//create pie data object
PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.RED);/* only YValue color changes, Xvalues         remains white*/
pieData.setValueFormatter(new valueFormat());
pieChart.setData(pieData);
//pieDataSet.notifyDataSetChanged();
//pieChart.invalidate();
```

Please Help . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
int colorBlack = Color.parseColor("#000000");
pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(colorBlack);
```